# How I can change the layout in an adapter?

Tags: android, listview, layout, adapter

I'm filling a listview with a custom adapter, but now, I want to change the layout of the row if the id is contains in an array.

This my code:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;

        CalcHolder holder = new CalcHolder();
        PojoCalc f = calcList.get(position);

        Integer[] calcs_lite = {6, 8, 18, 37, 51, 75};

        boolean exists = containsValue(calcs_lite, f.get_id());

        // First let's verify the convertView is not null
        // Value exist, so, we enable layout
        if (convertView == null) {
            // This a new view we inflate the new layout
            if(exists){
                Log.e("AdapterCalc1", "VALUE:::" + exists + ":::ID:::" + f.get_id() + ":::NAME:::" + f.getName() + ":::AVAILABLE");
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calc_row_adapter, null);
            }else{
                Log.e("AdapterCalc1", "VALUE:::" + exists + ":::ID:::" + f.get_id() + ":::NAME:::" + f.getName() + ":::UNAVAILABLE");
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calc_row_adapter_disabled, null);
            }

            // Now we can fill the layout with the right values
            TextView tv_name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
            TextView tv_subtitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);


            holder.calcNameView = tv_name;
            holder.calcSubtitleView = tv_subtitle;

            v.setTag(holder);
        }
        else{
            holder = (CalcHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        holder.calcNameView.setText(f.getName());
        holder.calcSubtitleView.setText(f.getSubtitle());


        return v;
    }
```

The first time I get the list, It works, but when I pull down to retrieve more elements, it fails, it doesn't change the view right. I think that there is a problem in the "else" with the holder, but I am not sure.

Comment: The problem is because `if (convertView == null)` condition will be false when you scroll as the view already exists and is whatever you've already inflated the first time you created your view. RecyclerView handles this situation much better than ListView but if you have to use a listview, have a look at `getItemViewType` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html) and see how you can use it. This is a good example that explains the concepts better https://guides.codepath.com/android/Implementing-a-Heterogenous-ListView

Answer (score 1):

1.override  getItemViewType and getViewTypeCount in you custom adapter
2.use getItemViewType in getView

Answer (score 1):

This is because the list view is re-using each row and you are trying to set different layout for each row can you please make both layout in one file and toggle it ie(hide /visible) as you want it

```
   if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) _context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.grid_list_item, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.btn_delete_photo = (Button) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.btn_delete_photo);
        holder.im_photo = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.im_photo);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    DataHolderClassName item = itemList.get(position);

    holder.btn_delete_photo.setTag(item);
    holder.im_photo.setTag(item);

    if(exist)
    {
    hide();
    }else{
    visible();}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are everything fine...just pass viewgroup to the inflate() method and add third parameter as false
just like

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;

    CalcHolder holder = new CalcHolder();
    PojoCalc f = calcList.get(position);

    Integer[] calcs_lite = {6, 8, 18, 37, 51, 75};

    boolean exists = containsValue(calcs_lite, f.get_id());

    // First let's verify the convertView is not null
    // Value exist, so, we enable layout
    if (convertView == null) {
        // This a new view we inflate the new layout
        if(exists){
            Log.e("AdapterCalc1", "VALUE:::" + exists + ":::ID:::" + f.get_id() + ":::NAME:::" + f.getName() + ":::AVAILABLE");
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calc_row_adapter, parent, false); //changes in this line
        }else{
            Log.e("AdapterCalc1", "VALUE:::" + exists + ":::ID:::" + f.get_id() + ":::NAME:::" + f.getName() + ":::UNAVAILABLE");
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calc_row_adapter_disabled, parent, false); //changes in this line
        }

        // Now we can fill the layout with the right values
        TextView tv_name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView tv_subtitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);


        holder.calcNameView = tv_name;
        holder.calcSubtitleView = tv_subtitle;

        v.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{
        holder = (CalcHolder) v.getTag();
    }

    holder.calcNameView.setText(f.getName());
    holder.calcSubtitleView.setText(f.getSubtitle());


    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a mix of your responses. I change the line of the inflater, and I change dynamically the layout, making changes in colors.

The final code is this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;

        LinearLayout ll_row;
        TextView tv_name, tv_subtitle;

        CalcHolder holder = new CalcHolder();
        PojoCalc f = calcList.get(position);

        Integer[] calcs_lite = {6, 8, 18, 37, 51, 75};

        boolean exists = containsValue(calcs_lite, f.get_id());

        // First let's verify the convertView is not null
        // Value exist, so, we enable layout
        if (convertView == null) {
            // This a new view we inflate the new layout
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calc_row_adapter, parent, false); //changes in this line

            // Now we can fill the layout with the right values
            ll_row = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.ll_row);
            tv_name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
            tv_subtitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);


            if(exists){
                ll_row.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                tv_name.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                tv_subtitle.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            }else{
                ll_row.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
                tv_name.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                tv_subtitle.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
            }

            holder.calcNameView = tv_name;
            holder.calcSubtitleView = tv_subtitle;

            v.setTag(holder);
        }
        else{
            // Now we can fill the layout with the right values
            ll_row = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.ll_row);
            tv_name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
            tv_subtitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);

            if(exists){
                ll_row.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                tv_name.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                tv_subtitle.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            }else{
                ll_row.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
                tv_name.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                tv_subtitle.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
            }


            holder = (CalcHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        holder.calcNameView.setText(f.getName());
        holder.calcSubtitleView.setText(f.getSubtitle());


        return v;
    }
```

Thanks